# get-vm not working in a switch parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, windows-scripting

So,
I'm trying to train my Powershell shins, I'm new to scripting and I've tried to do a simple script of managing `VM's` (things like, show all the `VM's` stop, suspend etc)

so here is the code:
i've also tried to write only "get-vm" it's not working to

```
do
{
    $input = Read-Host " what do you want to do? 
                        `n1)  list all the Vms
                        `n2) do something to the Vms?
                        `n
                        `n * what is your choice?"
    switch ($input)
    {
        '1' { 'you choose to show all the avalibale VMs on the pc'
                $mypcs = "localhost"
                get-vm -computername $mypcs
            }
        '2' {
            cls
            'You chose option #2'
            }
        '3' {
            cls
            'You chose option #3'
            }
        'q' {
            return
            }
    }
    pause
}
until ($input -eq 'q')
```

and I'm getting this:

> Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
>   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace

if i run `get-vm` I'm getting the list of my `VM's` on the PC without any problem.

PS: don't give the answer, if you could please direct me to the answer,
thanks a lot.

any one?
please?

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete, making it almost impossible to diagnose which `{ }` pair it's complaining about - please post the entire `switch` statement

Comment: i've added all the code
sorry if it's not readable i'm getting some problems to add it in the right blocks on the site, correctly

Comment: I have tried your code and I don't get any error.

Comment: when you are getting the error, soon after executing the code or after giving input ? it should be while executing ...